# Drag the canvas line corners afer drawing it in android

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, touch, android-canvas

I am developing an android app on mapview v1. In that, I had drawn polygon using canvas drawline option.Now, I want to alter the corners of polygon for the correction by user touch after getting the output ( drawing that).

Refer the follwing link: It will show my actual requirement.

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2ushddy&s=8#.U8YRpJSSy80

I dont get any idea to alter the corners of line after drawing it. How can i do this?...

Thanks in advance....

Here is my code.... (I had drawn the lines successfully but i dont know how to drag its endpoints.)

```
class MyOverlay extends Overlay{

public MyOverlay(){

}

public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapv, boolean shadow){

super.draw(canvas, mapv, shadow);
projection = mapv.getProjection();
 Paint mPaint = new Paint();
 mPaint.setDither(true);
mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
 mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
 mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
 mPaint.setStrokeWidth(14);

Paint mPaint1 = new Paint();
 mPaint1.setDither(true);
 mPaint1.setColor(Color.BLUE);
 mPaint1.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
 mPaint1.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
 mPaint1.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
 mPaint1.setStrokeWidth(1);
 mPaint1.setTextSize(18);

 try
 {

Point ppo = new Point();
 Point ppo1 = new Point();

for( m=0;m<j+1;m++)  
{       
if(m==0)
anglem =Math.abs(v[0]); 
else
anglem =Math.abs(v[0] - v[m]);
 x1[m]= (dis[m]*1000)*Math.sin(anglem*Math.PI / 180);
 y1[m]= (dis[m]*1000)*Math.cos(anglem*Math.PI / 180);



 GeoPoint gpo = new GeoPoint((int)(x1[m]),(int)(y1[m]));
 projection.toPixels(gpo, ppo);

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Distance"+dis[m], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
if(m>0)
{

     Path pathoo1 = new Path();
     pathoo1.moveTo(ppo1.x, ppo1.y);
    pathoo1.lineTo(ppo.x,ppo.y);
    canvas.drawPath(pathoo1, mPaint);
    mPaint1.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    canvas.drawTextOnPath((sf.format(Math.round(distance[m-1] * 100) / 100)).toString()+ " ft", pathoo1,25 ,25, mPaint1);
}

ppo1.x=ppo.x;ppo1.y=ppo.y;

}
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Wrong" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

 }

}
```

Comment: Post your code that you have tried.

Comment: I had posted my code now... how can i proceed further?